# Problema em manter aspas

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
famous_person = "Dalai Lama disse:\n"

message = "\Se quer viver uma vida feliz, amarre-se a uma meta, não a pessoas nem a coisas\"

print(famous_person + message)
```

Já tentei de tudo (inclusive pôr duas aspas). Se coloco duas aspas à esquerda dá erro, se for à direita fico sem aspa esquerda... Gostava de manter as duas.

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema, vc pode escolher a que melhor resolveu e aceitá-la, [veja aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 2):

Para deixar seu código mais limpo, você pode definir a string com aspas simples, assim as aspas duplas da mensagem não interferirão na sintaxe:

```
texto = '"Mensagem entre aspas"'
```

Lembrando que o Python permite você definir a string de quatro formas: aspas simples, duplas, trio de aspas simples e trio de aspas duplas (as duas últimas para string de múltiplas linhas). Independente de qual utilizar, as outras três serão consideradas como texto dentro da string.

Answer (score 1):

Para por aspas em um string você deve usar `\`:

```
message = "\"Se quer viver uma vida feliz, amarre-se a uma meta, não a pessoas nem a coisas\""
```

A barra invertida (`\`) serve para anular o efeito de um símbolo especial da linguagem dentro da string, deixando ele apenas como símbolo.

Comment: Funcionou :) Vlw pela explicação, é sempre bom aprender kkkk

Comment: hehe de nada e um prazer poder ajudar. :D

Answer (score 1):

Acrescentando uma terceira opção, é possível usar as sequências `""" ... """` ou `''' ... '''` para delimitar as *strings* sem a necessidade de escapar as aspas e apóstrofos dentro dela:

```
>>> a = '''Disse ele: "era uma vez um gato xadrez" '''
>>> b = """e 'todos' ficaram "perplexos" com a afirmação."""
>>> print a + b
```

E o resultado: `Disse ele: "era uma vez um gato xadrez" e 'todos' ficaram "perplexos" com a afirmação.`